# "Unparsable date" when trying to reformat a date String

Tags: java

I want to reformat a given date String into a different format:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' KK:mm aa zzzz");   
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(question.getOccur());
String formattedTime = output.format(d);
```

I'm getting this exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Monday, December 7, 2015 at 12:05:13 PM Eastern Standard Time" (at offset 33)

Comment: You're missing the seconds characters in your format String.

Comment: And the `Locale` (if the default is not `ENGLISH` or similar).

Comment: @awezshaikh Please compare `KK:mm` with `12:05:13`, then you know what is missing.

Comment: could you please post the correct code

Comment: `"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' KK:mm:ss aa zzzz"`

Answer (score 1):

You missed the seconds from your date format.
Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' KK:mm:ss aa zzzz");   
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(question.getOccur());
String formattedTime = output.format(d);
```

---

Edit. For the following example: Thursday 12/10/2015 01:35 AM, the date format is this:

```
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
```

Comment: i want like this Thursday 12/10/2015 01:35 AM

Comment: @awezshaikh Then you need to use a corresponding `output` format, since *"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"* certainly looks different.

Comment: Change your date format like this: `SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");`

Comment: @cylon *""dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm""* also doesn't look like "Thursday 12/10/2015 01:35 AM".

Comment: Yes, you are right :) Maybe the following format will be ok: `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a`

Comment: "Thursday" is still missing ;P

Comment: I hope this finally is correct: `EEEE dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a` :D

Comment: No, but you're almost there :D. You might want to recheck *"Thursday 12/10/2015 01:35 AM"* with your `EEEE dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a`. There is a small difference ;).

Comment: Replacing dashes with slashes? :) I bet @awezshaikh figured it out already.